# How do you programmatically import files in Google Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm looking at this example which uses deployment manager to deploy a cloud function: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloud_functions

One of the things that makes this unwieldy and not very usable is this, it requires you explicitly import EVERY file in the function:

```
imports:
- path: cloud_function.py
# The function code will be defined for the files in function/
- path: function/index.js
- path: function/package.json
```

It's not acceptable to have to add to that every time there is a new file. Deployment Manager also does not support wildcards.

How can you import files programmatically?

This is the part of cloud_function.py that references the imported files, I tried to just use a string but it seems that import actually copies files somewhere? How do I do that programmatically so I don't need to explicitly define every individual file?

```
  files = ["function/index.js","function/package.json"] # this does not work if these files have not been declared via "import"
  #for imp in ctx.imports:
  for imp in files:
    if imp.startswith(ctx.properties['codeLocation']):
      zip_file.writestr(imp[len(ctx.properties['codeLocation']):],
                        ctx.imports[imp])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn on [globbing](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_deployment_manager), in this way config files can now use glob patterns in import paths:

> gcloud config set deployment_manager/glob_imports True

Here are [examples](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/at-scale#best_practices) where entire folders can be added:

```
imports:
- path: templates/simple_frontend.py
  name: simple_frontend.py

# Helper classes
- path: helper/*.py

# Configuration files
- path: configs/*.yaml
- path: configs/*/*.yaml
```

The full documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/at-scale).

Comment: well thats great! do I have to set a config like this though `gcloud config set deployment_manager/glob_imports True`. Is there a switch I can just pass to the `gcloud deployment-manager` command? that would be nice

Comment: You need to issue this command `gcloud config set deployment_manager/glob_imports True` in the [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell#launching_from_the_console). However could you elaborate on what you mean by "a switch I can just pass to the gcloud deployment-manager command?" ?

Comment: I just meant passing that as a command flag to the `gcloud deployment-manager` command instead of settings it first globally

Comment: This feature can only be enabled using the command above at this time.